# problem running Skype on Trusty Tahr (64 bits)

Tags: nvidia, 14.04, skype, shared-library

I have successfully installed Skype using Ubuntu Software Center. When I tried running from command line, I received the following error message:

```
$ skype
skype: error while loading shared libraries: libGL.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

If I tried doing it through `optirun` (i.e. forcing NVIDIA's graphic card) it works flawlessly. I'm sure this library is installed for both 32 and 64 bits.

How can I get it working?

I'm using a Asus Q550 laptop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently Skype is looking for `libGL.so` in somewhere it is not. My solution was to create a link to the right path in `/usr/lib32/`:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/i386-gnu-linux/mesa/libGL.so.1 /usr/lib32/
sudo ldconfig
```

It completely fixed it ([source](https://bugs.launchpad.net/linuxmint/+bug/1188696)).

Answer (score 1):

for me this works better:

```
$ cd /usr/lib32/
$ sudo ln -s /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/mesa/libGL.so.1 libGL.so.1
$ sudo ldconfig
```

Thanks anyway! Your message lead me to the right method and helped me solve it: (In Ubuntu Unicorn, Bento Remix).

Comment: Nice you got it working... but it's basically the same thing! :-)